# Server side screenshot with puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, server-side-rendering

Im trying to build an api with and endpoint that renders some html but no reponse, it only save an screenshot of that html in the server.
After doing some research i found something similar could be done with puppeteer or another headless browser, but i have a problem.

The structure that i nedd is.

Client -> API ->(Provide the content to render) Response -> Puppeteer -> Save image.

As you can see, i want puppeteer to get the response directly from the api.
The problem is every example needs an intermediary API that serves that html so you can make request to that secondary api with puppeteer.

Client -> API ->(Provide url) Puppeteer -> Secondary API -> Response -> Puppeteer -> Save image

Is there any way to avoid the second API.
I want to pass the data directly to puppeteer, not an url to make another request.

Thank you

Comment: You need something in the middle. You have to think that, at the end of the day, what you have is a browser that needs to browse a page.

Comment: So its the normal behaviour? I thought it was a very complicated idea to be right.
Maybe saving the html in a file and then open it with puppeteer?

Comment: That's also valid, technically speaking is the same, and API in de middle between the user and the html.